# Booking sheet with list of room no by the current month in year

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is rooms table for room information where tag rooms number and rooms details Table [Room Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyIS5.png).
This is booking table for booking information where tag customer id from customer table,hotel id from hotel list table,check-in-date,check-out-date,booked via etc table[Booking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK6TV.png).
This is room book table for booked rooms tag with booking id,room id,hotel id etc table[Room Book table][3].

Actually i solved half code table [Rooms booked overview][4]
my code is.

```
    $date = $_GET['sdate'];
    $parts = explode('-', $date);
    $likedata = $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1];
    $end = $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1] . '-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); 
    $monthNum = $parts[1];
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
    $data['monthname'] = $dateObj->format('F');

    $data['sdate'] = $date;
    $data['edate'] = $end;
    $data['sssdate'] = $date;
    $data['esdate'] = $end;
    $data['rooms'] = $this->user_model->get_room([
    'hotel_id' => $this->session->userdata('hotel_id')]);
    $data['room_book'] = $this->user_model->get_room_book([
    'hotel_id' => $this->session->userdata('hotel_id'), 
    'book_from like' => $likedata . '%']);
    $this->load->view('overview2_view', $data);
```

i want like this table [like this][5]
please help thanks to advance.

Comment: You mind editing your post a bit, 2 of your images are not uploaded correctly

Comment: actually my current reputation less than 10 so i can not upload more than 2 links

Comment: but you can upload image i guess

Comment: but how can i do?

Comment: now my reputation is 9

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137124/codeigniter lets talk over here. its good to prolong discussion in comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496851/how-to-upload-pictures-to-stackoverflow-for-posting